# A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x1f (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
ets_main.c 371

I am getting this error in my esp32 devkit v1
How to solve it?
I am using arduino IDE for programming the esp32

Comment: google the error ... you really need to do research first, post a question if research fails to resolve your problem

Comment: do you have the right com port selected? or CH340 driver si missing? the error in title is from console, the message in text is from Serial Monitor?

Comment: @Juraj the error is in serial monitor of arduino IDE